# Error when using INSERT INTO inside CASE statement

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to insert values into a table inside a `CASE` statement, but I'm getting the error "missing expression" in my `INSERT INTO`.

What is the correct way to use `INSERT INTO` within `CASE`? You can find the code below. I am using this `SELECT` statement in a procedure, and I'm putting the result of this into a cursor.

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(a.file_type,b.file_type) AS file_type,a.input AS a_input,b.input AS b_input,a.output AS a_output,b.output AS b_output,
    CASE WHEN a.input = b.input THEN
              input_num+1
          WHEN a.input <> b.input THEN
          INSERT INTO diff_values(file_type,a_input,b_input,report_date)
              SELECT file_type,a.input,b.input FROM  test1 a, tset2 b WHERE 
              a.file_type=b.file_type
        WHEN a.output = b.output THEN 
              out_num+1
    END CASE
FROM
  test1 a, tset2 b
         WHERE a.file_type=b.file_type
         AND a.report_date=b.report_date;
```

Comment: Well, your insert lists 4 columns (file_type,a_input,b_input,report_date) but you are only providing 3 values (file_type,a.input,b.input) which is invalid. On a related matter, my pl/sql is a bit rusty but I am not sure if an insert is allowed in a case statement (it might be), but for maintainability I would suggest breaking this into 2 separate statements. one to insert and the other to select. Most people do not expect select statements to write to the DB and thus will easily miss this when trying to debug issues in the future.

Comment: CASE *expression* Sigh...

Answer (score 1):

- You cannot embed a DML statement (e.g. `INSERT`) within a SQL query.
- You cannot embed a CASE *statement* (which is PL/SQL) within a SQL query. You *can* embed a CASE *expression* within a SQL query, however, but the expression can only evaluate a result, it cannot include PL/SQL (see #1 above)*.

The outcome you seem to want to achieve is to query some data from two tables (`test1` and `tset2`), evaluate an expression, and insert the result back into the same tables as new records. Since your final outcome is an `INSERT`, you would start with that and then create a query that gathers the data needed for it, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO diff_values(file_type,a_input,b_input,report_date)
SELECT a.file_type,
       a.input,
       b.input,
       a.report_date
FROM test1 a, tset2 b
WHERE a.file_type=b.file_type
AND a.report_date=b.report_date
AND a.input <> b.input;
```

Note that I've removed the COALESCE because the WHERE clause guarantees both a.file_type and b.file_type are identical anyway, so you can just refer to one of those columns.

Now, your original statement included the following lines as well:

```
WHEN a.input = b.input THEN
     input_num+1
...
WHEN a.output = b.output THEN
      out_num+1
```

I don't know what these are supposed to do, but I suppose you could write additional queries to detect these conditions and output the results.

- *technically, in Oracle 12.1 you can include procedural code in a WITH clause within SQL https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1*